# Flow (code-editor extension)

Tags: app, stackoverflow, extension

### Screenshot

Get code instantly:

[image]

Simple navigation between results
[image]

Dive in to get more info about the code-snippet
[image]

### About

Flow is a code-editor extension for programmers, that integrates the power of the internet into your editor, by helping you search for code-snippets and examples for any programming task.

Flow automates the process of browsing through Q&A sites (like StackOverflow) and reading exhausting online documentation.
Currently supports Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, 2012, 2013 - but in the future, sublime and eclipse's variants will be supported as well.

For more info, please visit our homepage (link below).

#### License

FREE (for commercial use too).

#### Download

http://www.flowextension.com

#### Platform

PC with Microsoft Visual Studio 2010, 2012, or 2013.

### Contact

Contact us via our website: 
[http://www.flowextension.com](http://www.flowextension.com/blog)

Comment: Its a while ago, but has this been retired?